# ksort in multidimensional array doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort the child arrays of an array by keys. Tried in a loop, doesn't seem to work.

```
$arr = array (
    15 => array (0=>'london',30=>'rome',21=>'berlin'),
    23 => array (0=>'london',34=>'rome',20=>'berlin'),
    19 => array (0=>'london',31=>'rome',22=>'berlin'),
  );


foreach ($arr as $item) {
    ksort($item);
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried [array_multisort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)?

Comment: isn't array_multisort sorting by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify `$item` PHP will automatically create a copy and only change that copy. To prevent that you can use a reference:

```
foreach ($arr as &$item)
```

Or you can modify `$arr`directly:

```
 foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
   ksort($item);
   $arr[$key] = $item;
 }
```